# Is there another way to find the truth value of an argument?

Tags: logic

my question is: Is there a quicker way to find the truth value of an argument rather than using truth tables?

IE:

p -> ~q
q

---

therefor not p

The value of this is valid/true. But I used the truth table for it. Any other way?

Comment: The fastest way here is to make use of the *modus tollens* rule of inference.

Comment: And what is that rule ?

Comment: For an implication, assign thuth values so that the antecedent is true. Then check to see if the consequent is false or not. If the consequent is false, then the argument is false, and the argument is true/valid if the consequent is true.

Comment: assign thuth values?

Comment: I've answered this question below. But you are asking a lot of very elementary questions which suggest that you need to start reading a good textbook before asking more here. Paul Teller's excellent *Modern Formal Logic Primer* is freely available here: http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu (and P*t*r Sm*th's equally excellent book from any library/bookshop!)

Answer (score 1):

1) An argument does not have a truth-value. *Propositions*, including of course, the premisses and conclusions of particular arguments, are true or false. But an *argument* isn't true or false. We may assess it as valid or invalid (the inference move is such that the truth of the premisses guarantees the truth of the conclusion), or as sound or unsound (the argument is valid and has true premisses). But not as plain true or false.

2) So the question should be rephrased as one about whether there are other ways of establishing an argument's *validity* than by the use of truth-tables. Yes. By providing a *deduction* of the conclusion from the premisses, using more fundamental rules of inference (though obviously, at some point, you'll have to take *some* rules as given). And once you go beyond a very restricted class of arguments, there is  nothing like a truth-table test to rely on, and you have to use some species of deductive proof to show that a given argument is indeed valid.

3) You can warrant the modus tollens argument you give by this kind of reasoning in a standard natural deduction system:

> 1. $p \to \neg q\quad$ (premiss)
> 2. $q\quad\quad\quad$  (premiss)
> 3. $\quad | \quad p\quad$(temporary assumption)
> 4. $\quad | \quad \neg q\quad$(by modus ponens from 1, 3)
> 5. $\quad |\quad$ Contradiction!!! (from 2 and 4)
> 6. $\neg p\quad$ (since the temporary assumption at 3 leads to absurdity).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat to your point, the general process for demonstrating the compatibility of a series of propositions is called a *derivation*,  and it is essentially a step-by-step decomposition of a series of statements until it is laid bare whether they are compatible or not.